# Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java

Tags: java, eclipse-kepler

I have created a New Dynamic Project under Eclipse Kepler Version, where my JRE Version is set to 1.8.

> Java compiler set to 1.8

After setting the JRE version to 1.8 got the below exception.

> Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java
>   project facet.

I have checked the Project facet set to 1.7. I changed it to 1.8 by changing in this file `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`.

> After changing version of java in the above file got another warning :
>   implementation of version 1.8 of project facet java could not be found
>
> I found one link which has the almost same issue but not able to
>   solved my issue :
>   [Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715260/java-compiler-level-does-not-match-the-version-of-the-installed-java-project-fac)

How to solved this issue?

Comment: what is Java Compiler settings in project properties? do right click of `Project->properties->JavaCompiler`

Comment: @bmt Added compiler settings

Comment: refer this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955207/version-1-8-of-project-facet-java-does-not-exist

Comment: Do you use maven? In Intellij IDEA if you don't specify maven compile plugin with your JDK version it is always `1.5`. Maybe Eclipse does the same thing

Comment: @coolguy I am not using maven.

Comment: If you want to use Java 8 you would be better off moving to the current Eclipse Mars as that has improved support for Java 8 features such as lambda expressions.