# Version 9 of project facet java does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

I have installed:

- [Java 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html)
- [Eclipse Oxygen](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Oxygen/1)
- [Java 9 Support for Oxygen](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen)

When project compliance level is 9, I get:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Version 9 of project facet java does not exist.
```

If I try to [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955207/version-1-8-of-project-facet-java-does-not-exist) project -> Properties -> Project Facets -> Java, there is no option to select 1.9.

If I reduce compliance level to 1.8, the error disappears.

Do I need an additional plugin?

Comment: The answers here shall help you figure out a solution and probably wait until 11.10.2017 for a fully supported release from Eclipse.