# Eclipse has no Java facet version 1.8

Tags: eclipse, java-8, m2eclipse

I am using eclipse Kepler (enterprise edition), Java 8, and M2Eclipse and trying to make a web application.  I have already gone to help -> eclipse marketplace and installed these two patches:

- Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2
- Java 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2

Those patches cleared up a lot of my problems, but one remains.  I did a maven -> update from within eclipse, it went and updated all my projects except the only web app in my workspace.  It gives me a pop up message that says "Version 1.8 of project facet java does not exist"

I opened my project properties and clicked Project Facets.  Sure enough, the java facet maximum version is 1.7.  So I am wondering why I don't have the same problem on my other projects.  I viewed the properties on my other projects and discovered that none of them are using Project Facets at all.  I think this might be because I made all of the previous projects using a standard edition of eclipse, not an enterprise edition.

So I guess I have a couple questions.  How can I get eclipse to recognize the java facet 1.8?  Is there a way I can have my web app not use Project Facets?  Should I add Project Facets to my other projects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse + Java 8 + Dynamic Web Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479326/eclipse-java-8-dynamic-web-module)

Answer (score 10):

Just ran into this issue. My problem was with the tomcat server looking in the wrong place for the JRE. To fix that:

- Double click on the server in the servers tab
- Open "Runtime Environment"
- Change the JRE selector.

Hope this saves someones time

Comment: This fixed my issue. I installed a new Java version and deleted the old one and that was what caused the problem. Looking at the environment in the server showed that it was pointing to jars for a difference Java install. Basically it is easier to create a new server.

Answer (score 6):

I am using 4.3.2 version of Eclipse Kepler SR2 and ran into the same issue when the java version was bumped up from 1.7 to 1.8 for our maven project.

I was getting the following error while trying to do Maven Update :
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". Version 1.8 of project facet java does not exist.

If you check the Java Project Facet Version (Right click on project -> Properties -> Search for Project Facets -> Java (Version)) .. it must be an older version.

[Project Facet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPShM.png)

Solution :

Goto Eclipse Marketplace and install the following :

1. Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2
2. Java 8 Facet for Web Tools for Eclipse Kepler SR2

Now, change the Java Project Facet Version  to 1.8

Right click on project -> Properties -> Search for Project Facets -> Java (Version)

Now, you should be able to successfully take a maven update.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this in eclipse, go to "Help" --> "Market Place" --> Search  java 8 kepler. Then install all the 3 below plugins

install Java 8 support eclipse kepler sr2,
install Java 8 Facets for web tools eclipse kepler sr2
install Java 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2 (if you are using maven)

Reference: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/

or You can try this

Select Project properties -->Project facets than at there change your java to the version of your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project > properties > java > compiler > compliance level > set it to 1.8

Comment: I said in the question that I tried that, 1.8 did not exist.  I was missing another patch, apparently there were three I needed for java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem. I did like the below.

**Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path.**

*On that, select Java Build Path, if there is any wrong mark indicated in the JRE System Library, select Library Tab and add JRE Library.*

Once JRE Library added successfully, select the JRE System Library in Order and Export Tab and then click ok.

Then restart your eclipse.

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when our project upgraded from jdk 1.7 to 1.8 and server Tomcat to JBOSS. When I checked the Targeted Runtimes (Project-->right click-->properties-->Targeted Runtimes), it was pointing to Tomcat, and as I changed it to JBOSS the Project facets gave me java 1.8 version.