# After importing from a git in eclipse I get the error "source folder is not java project"

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I know other people have had this problem, but I can't get it to work.

I imported a project from a git and I get an error saying "Project is not a Java project" when adding a class and it doesn't show up in the run config. [Project here if it is something wrong with the project and not eclipse](https://gitlab.com/LostWalker/freepie-mapper). I've heard answers to this with project facet and maven, but I don't have either.

I am running the latest version of eclipse and clean installed it today

Comment: @Lost Your GitLab project is a private one, so not visible by the rest of us. What version of Eclipse/Java/Git are you using, and on which OS?

Comment: Whoops. Made it public now. Eclipse version 4.9.0, Windows 10 on version 1803, Java jdk is 10.0.1, jre is 10.0.2, Eclipse EGit 5.1.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error should be "[“Source folder is not a Java project”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719545/source-folder-is-not-a-java-project-error-in-eclipse)".

Check the content of your `.project` and .classpath.

You can [modify the `.project`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179450/6309) to add the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature` manually.
(But [adding the java facet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31965240/6309) should be the recommended way)

- regarding the lack of Java facet, make sure your Eclipse has the right Java version support, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34941218/6309).
- a `.project` and `.classpath` [can be manually generated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085726/6309) or copied from another simple Java Eclispe project.

Comment: Looks like I'm missing a .classpath and my .project is quite empty That's probably where my problems are coming from. I feel like it would probably be best to copy paste my code into a new project and just push that to my git. I'll try that tomorrow unless there is some way to re-generate the project and classpath files. On another note, I don't have java facets. Even when I select properties of a fully functional project

Comment: @LostWalker Agreed. i have updated the answer to address the lack of Java facet or project files.